# Remove the string between the last two slashes in a URL

Tags: javascript

I have the following url:
`http://website.com/testing/test2/`

I want to remove the text between the last two slashes so this would produce:
`http://website.com/testing/`

Comment: Use the regex pattern: `/(http://.*?\/)[^\/]+\//`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it is the best solution but it is simple and working:

```
var s = 'http://website.com/testing/test2/';
var a = s.split('/');

s = s.replace(a[a.length-2] + '/', '');
alert(s);`
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/xkhu92u0/1

Comment: The JS fiddle is still alerting the whole URL.

Answer (score 1):

Here we get the last slash index in the string and subsctring from beginning to the slash index

```
 text = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf("/")
```

that will result:

```
"http://website.com/testing/test2"  // text
```

then did the same again get the last slach index and substring to this index + 1 and the +1 to include the slash again in the substring

```
text = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
```

this will result:

```
"http://website.com/testing/"   // text
```

do it in 1 line:

```
text = "http://website.com/testing/test2/"

text = text.substring(0, text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf("/")).lastIndexOf("/")+1)
```

Comment: And...? Please add an explanation as to why this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = 'http://website.com/testing/test2/', //URL to convert
    lastSlash = url.lastIndexOf('/'),          //Find the last '/'
    middleUrl = url.substring(0,lastSlash);    //Make a new string without the last '/'
lastSlash = middleUrl.lastIndexOf('/');        //Find the last '/' in the new string (the second last '/' in the old string)
var newUrl = middleUrl.substring(0,lastSlash); //Make a new string that removes the '/' and everything after it
alert(newUrl);                                 //Alert the new URL, ready for use
```

This works.

Comment: It might not be the fastest, but it definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var missingLast = url.substring(0, url.substring(0, url.length - 1).lastIndexOf('/'));
```

This will ignore the last slash first, then it will ignore the second to last slash.

**NOTE:** If you want to keep the last slash just add one to lastIndexOf like so:

```
var missingLast = url.substring(0, url.substring(0, url.length - 1).lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,

```
var url = 'http://website.com/testing/test2/';
var arr = url.split('/');
var lastWord = arr[arr.length-2];
var newUrl = url.substring(0, url.length-lastWord.length-1);
alert(newUrl);
```

demo in [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/knajgkpa/)