# Get string between the last two slash positions in a URL in Python

Tags: python, string

I am working to slice an HTML address to get the unique part and use it as my filename.

Here is the challenge:

- http://www.someurl.com/folder-1/somestring/01.pdf
- http://www.someurl.com/folders1531as12/anotherstring/183.pdf
- http://www.someurl.com/folder-dsa990s/nostring/46798.pdf

I am trying to set the filename as:

```
somestring-01.pdf  
anotherstring-01.pdf  
nostring-01.pdf
```

Since there is no way of knowing how many characters after the last slash and between the last two slashes, I am not able to hard-define splits such as [-5:-10].

To be able to solve this challenge, my pseudo-code to get the filename is as follows:

- Find the index of the last string [int_last_slash_index]
- Find the index of the one previous string [int_prev_slash_index]
  Step 1: count no of slashes in string
  Step 2: subtract one from the count (count_slash-1)
  Step 3: find the (count_slash-1)th index position
- Set slicing positions:
  Position 1: last slash position = len(url) - int_last_slash_index
  Position_2: previous slash position = len(url) - int_prev_slash_index
- Slice the URL string with [-int_prev_slash_position:-int_last_slash_position]

In Python:

```
last_slash_index = url_string.rfind("/")
int_last_slash_index = int(last_slash_index)
int_last_slash_position = len(url_string) - int(last_slash_index)
slash_count = url_string.count("/")
one_prev_slash = slash_count -1 
index_one_prev_slash = url_string.find("/",one_prev_slash)
int_one_prev_slash_index = int(index_one_prev_slash)
int_one_prev_slash_position = len(url_string) - 
int(int_one_prev_slash_index)
filename = url_string[-int_last_slash_position:-int_one_prev_slash_position]
```

If there is such a way, I want to solve it with string operators, rather than diving into regexes, code tricks because I cannot handle them now. I am OK to learn further methods, libraries though.

As you would guess, I am new in Python and just trying to get a hold of strings.

Thank you.

PS: Just the opposite was posted before but for Java, no responses: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785732/remove-the-string-between-the-last-two-slashes-in-a-url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use split:

```
urls = [
    "http://www.someurl.com/folder-1/somestring/01.pdf",
    "http://www.someurl.com/folders1531as12/anotherstring/183.pdf",
    "http://www.someurl.com/folder-dsa990s/nostring/46798.pdf",
]
for url in urls:
    print(url.split('/')[-2])
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) using `'/'` as the separator, from the documentation:

> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter
>   string.

Code:

```
urls = ['http://www.someurl.com/folder-1/somestring/01.pdf',
'http://www.someurl.com/folders1531as12/anotherstring/183.pdf',
'http://www.someurl.com/folder-dsa990s/nostring/46798.pdf']

for url in urls:
    print('{}-{}'.format(*url.split('/')[-2:]))
```

**Output**

```
somestring-01.pdf
anotherstring-183.pdf
nostring-46798.pdf
```

Once the url is splitted you can get the last two elements of the list and combine them using the [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import urllib3

url = r"http://www.someurl.com/folder-1/somestring/01.pdf"
print("-".join(urllib3.util.parse_url(url).path.split("/")[-2:]))
```

this would also work in case of more complicated urls

ex: http://www.someurl.com/folder-1/somestring/01.pdf?x=1

Answer (score 0):

After days of scratching my bald head, I am illuminated with rsplit method.
Instead of all the algorithm above, this did everything:

```
filename = url_string.rsplit("/")[-2]
```

Apologies for taking everybody's time and efforts. And thanks very much for the comments.